# Replace w/Alphabet Position Challenge in Code Wars: getting right result but not passing any tests?

Tags: python

I am working on the "Replace With Alphabet Position" challenge in Code Wars. For some reason, I have been getting the exact same results as the sample tests but I'm not passing any of the sample tests. I'm thinking that maybe my output type is still a list even though I tried converting it to a string? Any advice?

```
from string import *

def alphabet_position(text):
    alphabet_dict = {}
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    value = 0
    spaceless_list = []
# assigns values to letters
    for letter in alphabet:
        value += 1
        alphabet_dict.update( {letter : value} )
# checks dictionary keys for letter value and adds letter value to list; excludes spaces and "
    for unit in text:
        if unit.lower() in alphabet_dict.keys():
            letter_value = alphabet_dict.get(unit.lower(), unit)
            spaceless_list.append(letter_value)
        elif unit == ' ' or "'":
            del unit
            continue
        else:
            continue
    list_to_str = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in spaceless_list])
    print(f"'{list_to_str}'")
```

***Test Results:***
Log: ***'20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11'***

***None should equal '20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11'***

Comment: Does your function return anything?

Comment: @iamvegan yeah, it's what's written in the log right?

Comment: Your functions certainly prints something, but from your code I don't see any `return` statement.

Comment: @iamvegan Ugh, I thought about what you asked and just figured out I was printing not returning anything. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

I was printing my code rather than returning it. Question is solved.